# How do I save the Numbers document I'm working on?

Tags: numbers

Using Numbers 3.6.2, and would like to save document to finish later. Where do I save it? (Saving to PDF is permanent)

Answer (score 3):

You can save it anywhere you want.  Just do `Command-S` or go to `File --> Save` and it will bring up a dialog box.  You can use the default location or any other folder/location you want.

You can even save it to your iCloud account from the same dialog.  See the image below.

[image]